# Hide server version data in Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, server

I am optimizing my website with the rules of "Checkbot" and the alert appears in which it is necessary to Hide server version data but I can not find the way to do it, now try the following:

.htaccess

```
ServerSignature Off
```

php.ini (added manually to the server root)

```
expose_php = Off
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: which os you running on server , if it is ubuntu sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf and Change ServerTokens OS to ServerTokens Prod then Change ServerSignature On to ServerSignature Off and restart your apache

Comment: The server I use is shared, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the web server information by adding the following lines:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

`ServerSignature` can be disabled by adding the line in a `.htaccess` file. Unfortunately, you can use `ServerTokens` only in the web server configuration. If you don't have access to the configuration you won't be able to do it.

Comment: This generate a Internal Server Error.